# How to capture images from a flash application that runs in the background?

Tags: java, flash

I am trying to capture images from a flash application that runs in a browser and process them in a java application.

So far, I am using (simplified):

```
Robot r;
BufferedImage i = r.createScreenCapture();
```

However, to make this work the browser always has to be in the foreground, since this is just a simple screen capture.

My question: Is it possible to capture image data from applications that don't run in the foreground or even access the flash application directly?

Note: It would also be okay, for me to do this with some script (e.g. in python) and then pass the data to the Java Application.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can with [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/):

Check the first answer in this post:

[Take a screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)

The used method's documentation: [TakesScreenshot.getScreenshotAs()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to take screenshots if the application is not in foreground. You can use Adrian's answer to take a screenshot if it is in foreground.